# Measure resource consumption

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-core-3.1, webapi

Ok I am a relative young developer and I started developing some web api application using ASP .Net Core 3.1, now what I want to to know if you guys know ways to actually measure a web api utilization, resource on our cloud server consumption.

I have deployed 3 web api on a VPS Cloud server, and I need to know which one consumes the most resources so I can evaluate switching to another server or maybe increaase server capacity, this is extremely important for me. If anyone knows a way to do this please any help would be greatly appreciated, dont want full answers, but a point in the right direction is actually needed as I am lost on this subject.

Kind regards,
Victor

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/diagnostics/event-counters Things like that are keys to learn runtime performance, and a search engine can lead you to more details.

Answer (score 0):

The Microsoft IIS Administration API is a REST API that enables consumers to configure and monitor their IIS web servers. With the API installed on an IIS machine, one can configure an IIS instance with any HTTP client including the web management tool at https://manage.iis.net.

The monitoring API provides performance and health data for the web server, web sites, and application pools. This data can be used to measure how effectively resources are being used.

For more information about it, you can refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis-administration/api/monitoring).